# Conditional typing for redux reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, types

I am trying to create a re-usable component that renders a 'select' form item and its associated options. It accepts **redux** prop that is an action creator that is responsible for passing the selected option into the redux store to be used throughout the application.

I have two action creators that are possible options:

The first is :

```
setCompany: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
        state.selectedCompany = action.payload;
    },
```

The second is:

```
setStatus: (state, action: PayloadAction<SelectStatus['status']>) => {
        state.status = action.payload;
    },
```

The JobState['status'] type is:   `status: 'success' | 'error' | 'default' | 'processing' | 'warning';`

In the Select component, I attempt to do the following:

```
interface SelectsProps {
fetchOptionData?: () => void;
optionsArray?: [];
placeholder: string;
showSearch: boolean;
badges: boolean;
redux?: ActionCreatorWithPayload<string | SelectStatus['status']>;
// I also tried ActionCreatorWithPayload<string> |                           //ActionCreatorWithPayload<SelectStatus['status']> but neither is working
}
```

In my parent component, i try to pass in a redux action of setStatus, defined above. However, I receive an error of :

```
`Type 'ActionCreatorWithPayload<"success" | "error" | "default" | "processing" | "warning", string>' is not assignable to type 'ActionCreatorWithPayload<string, string>'.`

   <Selects
                        redux={setStatus}
                        placeholder='Default'
                        showSearch={false}
                        badges={true}
                        optionsArray={badges}
                    />
    };
```

If I do it as a union, it seems to default to string and not accept a status to be passed if valid. Is there a way I can allow the correct payload type to be selected?

Thank you

Comment: Why is is `SelectStatus['status']` instead of `JobState['status']`?  Are they the same?  I think you need a union of the two action creators instead of an action creator of the union.  Try `redux?: ActionCreatorWithPayload<string> | ActionCreatorWithPayload<JobState['status']>`.

Comment: oops you are totally correct- SelectStatus and JobStatus are the same. I did also try to union the two action creators and still receive an error when doing the following:
@LindaPaiste
`const onSelect = (value: string | SelectStatus['status']) => {
  setSelectedOption(value);
                if (redux) dispatch(redux(value));
 };`
the error is : `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter 
of type '"success" | "error" | "default" | "processing" | "warning"`. 
hmmmmmmm

Comment: Ok that is to be expected because you might have `setStatus` which only accepts a `Status` so you cannot call it with an argument that could be either a `string` or a `Status`.  I would need to see more code in order to figure out a solution.  You might need to assert a type using `as` if your underlying `Select` can only deal with `string` (for example `e.target.value` is always just `string`).

Comment: Probably `Selects` need to be a generic component where the option values and the action creator use the same type `T`.

Comment: yeah i think you are totally right - i will try to refactor as a generic component rather than the messy way that I have it now. Thank you for your help. The union change did solve some issues and asserting a type helped me resolve another issue. I feel as if the code is muddied to the point that I am unsure of what I am doing :D

Comment: @LindaPaiste generic was the way to go!  Thanks so much. Lifechanger!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

You need a union of the two action creator types rather than an action creator of the union.

```
redux?: ActionCreatorWithPayload<string> | ActionCreatorWithPayload<SelectStatus["status"]>;
```

---

#### Explanation

`ActionCreatorWithPayload<string | SelectStatus['status']>` means an action creator that can be called with an argument of either `string` OR `SelectStatus['status']`.  `setCompany` is ok because `SelectStatus['status']` is a subset of `string`.  But `setStatus` is an error because it can only accept `SelectStatus['status']`.  It cannot accept the union.

You need the union of the two action creators which is `ActionCreatorWithPayload<string> | ActionCreatorWithPayload<SelectStatus["status"]>`.  This means that you can have a function that accepts `string` or a function that accepts `SelectStatus['status']`.  It no longer needs to accept the union of the two.

You may have problems when you call this union since you don't know which argument type it accepts.

---

Note: I don't know why you use `SelectStatus["status"]` is one place and `JobState["status"]` in the other.  I am assuming that they are the same.  I would extract that type to a named type:

```
export type JobStatus = JobState["status"]
```